# Wordpress upload bulky file issue

Tags: wordpress, file, upload

I am using CCF (Custom Contact Forms) plugin in which i need to have upload file field at the front end along with other fields. Max upload file size is 2MB that i defined in the plugin.

The issue is that if i try to upload bulky file (e.g 15MB) then form does not display any error and also does not upload files. The only thing happens is that the same form is just refreshed without showing any error even for other fields.

Is this the expected behavior or there is any way to come out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code to the plugin, in custom-contact-forms-front.php in function processFileUpload($field) I see:

```
if ($field->field_max_upload_size > 0 && $_FILES[$field->field_slug]['size'] > ($field->field_max_upload_size * 1000))
   $errors[] = basename($_FILES[$field->field_slug]['name']) . __(' is too large of a file. The maximum file size for that field is ', 'custom-contact-forms') . $field->field_max_upload_size . __(' KB.', 'custom-contact-forms');
```

Which is horrendously cryptic, IMO, but looks like it should be putting an error message in the $errors array. Down below I see

```
$upload_result = $this->processFileUpload($field, $post_time);
foreach ($upload_result as $err) {
$this->setFormError($field->field_slug, $err);
```

So it looks like the plugin attempts to create an error message. Would have to dig into some layers to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I have already gone through this code but unfortunately $_POST or $_FILES become empty array when i try to upload bulky file. Also i find that some other user has faced the same problem at the link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-custom-contact-forms-no-error-message-when-uploading-large-files-under-limit?replies=2 Not sure how to come out of this issue.

Comment: NEVER MIND, I GOT THE SOLUTION. The only thing i was missing that php does allow 8M by default for post_max_size for the form to be submitted. I just increased this ini setting and now i am getting the relevant error message for the file field as well as other fields too. So this issue is resolved.